# How to use combo box input to select work sheet to copy data to in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I think this is a simple question but as I haven't used excel in this way before I am struggling. I am trying to create a program based in Excel VBA. I work in a call center. We have numerous excel sheets to log calls for different schemes. I have a project to streamline this process. So far I have created a workbook that has separate sheets named to represent each scheme. I have created a userform to gather information. One of the combo boxes indicates which scheme the call is in regards to. The input from the userform needs to be logged on to a sheet in the work book that corresponds to the name of the scheme selected in the combo box. I cant seem to get this close to working. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!

The code I have is:

```
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()
Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub


Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim ShtName As String
ShtName = ComboBox1.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Add_Data
End Sub

Private Sub Add_Data()
Dim Worksheets As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim UserForm As Object
Dim iRow As Long


    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

Set ws = this.ComboBox1.GetItemText(this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem)


'find first empty row in database
iRow = ShtName.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Offset(1, 0).Row

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1) = Date
ws.Cells(iRow, 2) = Me.txtName.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3) = Me.txtNumber.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4) = ComboBox2.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.txtQuery.Value

If optYes = True Then
        msgstr = "Yes"
    ElseIf optNo = True Then
        msgstr = "No"

End If

ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = msgstr



If chkMain = True Then
        msgstri = "Main"
    ElseIf chkExec = True Then
        msgstr = "Exec"
     Else
        msgstri = ""

End If

ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = msgstri
ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Me.txtTime.Value




End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ComboBox1.Clear
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet2")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet3")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet4")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet5")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet6")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet7")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet8")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet9")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet10")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet11")
ComboBox1.AddItem ("Sheet12")

ComboBox2.Clear
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent1")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent2")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent3")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent4")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent5")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent6")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent7")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent8")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent9")
ComboBox2.AddItem ("agent10")

txtNumber.Value = ""
txtName.Value = ""
txtQuery.Value = ""
txtTime.Value = ""

optYes = False
optNo = False
chkMain = False
chkExec = False

ComboBox1.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting an error at

```
 Set ws = this.ComboBox1.GetItemText(this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
```

You are trying to set an object to a string. Try using

```
 Set ws = Sheets(this.ComboBox1.GetItemText(this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem))
```

This will actually give you the ws object in that variable. Sheets is the collection of worksheets in the workbook. You can select by index number or by the name of the sheet.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your help. I have now changed it as per your suggestion however I still get Runtime error 424 - object required... any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Sorry I should have said that. It happens when I click the submit button. The line that the debugger highlights is: the new line:        Set ws = Sheets(this.ComboBox1.GetItemText(this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem))

Comment: Well, I didn't notice it but the line you are using to collect the item from the combo isn't right. Try `Sheets(this.ComboBox1.BoundValue)` I'm going to test something and check. You might want to set up some sort of tester for your combo box that says `msgBox "Item is " & comboBox1.BoundValue` or whatever code you are using to get the value is to make sure what you are pulling is actually the sheet name.